# rtsp server using ffmpeg c code

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

I am using ffmpeg lib:

```
ffmpeg version git-2017-09-16-08ec828 
Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --enable-pic --enable-shared --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-postproc --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 75.100 / 55. 75.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
```

**Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder**

I am trying to write an **`RTSP`** server using the above version of **`ffmpeg`** libs. I have tried a large variety of approachess with no success. Has anyone already written such code with this **`ffmpeg`** version or does anyone know of such code? Or, do I need to change versions? Any suggestions or answers are welcome.

Comment: Did you check these ? :https://github.com/search?p=4&q=rtsp+server&type=Repositories

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen it already, but what I am searching for is a src/exp that using the ffmpeg lib